# Xamarin, hide calling screen?

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible to hide the calling screen behind a dialog or activity?

We want to show a custom calling screen hiding the called number and showing more information taken from a database. It should work both ways: when calling or receiving a call.

I have seen a video for a product called "A+ Call Manager" that can send the calling screen to background, anyone knows how they did that functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone that knows how to do something like this? http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2011/05/callbackgrounder-1024x606.jpg

The dialog over the screen would be good to display all the info or even better a whole activity.

Comment: Could it be done using an AlertDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could do it.

```
View mView = new View(this);
mView = LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.SomeLayout, null);
IWindowManager wm = (IWindowManager)GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
WindowManagerLayoutParams p = new WindowManagerLayoutParams()
{
    Type = WindowManagerTypes.PriorityPhone
};
wm.AddView(mView, p);
```

This creates an Activity over all others (including the call screen), but now I have another problem: that view won't update correctly! For example, if you put a Textedit and start writing on it and the erase a character it will still show it including the writable indicator.

Any of you have done something like this before? I would like to see that view animated just as a regular Activity.